# Mysql select data in the same row based on ID

Tags: mysql

could you advise how do we make this works? I have 2 tables:

```
timeslot_table
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| timeslot_id | timeslot_desc | timeslot_desc2|
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|       1     |      9:00     |      30 Mins  |
|       2     |      10:00    |      50 Mins  | 
|       3     |      11:00    |      40 Mins  |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

```
booking_table
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------+
| booking_id  | selected_time |   *slot_desc2*  |    Name   |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------+
|       1     |      11:00    |      40 Mins*   |    aaa    |
|       2     |      10:00    |      50 Mins*   |    bbb    |
|       3     |      9:00     |      30 Mins*   |    ccc    |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Booking table is getting selected_time values from timeslot_desc in timeslot_table using lookup function, same goes to *slot_desc2*, but how do we fill the *slot_desc2* value based on the timeslot_desc in timeslot_table? Like the example values show with * in booking_table?

To simplify, when the selected time is 11:00, the system will automatically lookup the value and put in the value "40 Mins" in slot_desc2, similarly when the selected time is 9:00, the system will automatically lookup in timeslot_table and put in the value "30 Mins" in *slot_desc2*.

The current selected_time codes:
`SELECT timeslot_desc, timeslot_desc  FROM timeslot_table  ORDER BY timeslot_table`

What would be the codes for *slot_desc2*?

Comment: Not with you - you seem to only need to add timeslot_desc2 to your query?? BTW you cannot order by a table you need to order by some column(s) in a table.

Comment: yes. but how do we make the sql statement for slot_desc2 based on selected_time? I'm not sure how..

Comment: I found the answer :) the expected output is the booking_table result above, we need to get value of timeslot_desc2 from timeslot_table WHERE timeslot_desc = selected_time.

Comment: expected output is the value marked with ** in booking table